# Windows 8.1 Custom Credential Provider working for one user

Tags: c++, windows-8, windows-8.1, user-accounts, credential-providers

I have customized the Windows 8/8.1 Credential Provider sample downloaded and as directed from the following link:

https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/V2-Credential-Provider-7549a730/view/Discussions

The credential provider works fine with no problem. When I boot up the windows, it shows my Sign-in options under the password field. When I click the sign-in options it shows me the icon for my custom provider. But when I created another user account, it doesn't give me additional sign-in options on the new account and only asks for password (default credential provider).

How can I use this custom provider with all user accounts available on the system? So that these sign-in options appear for every user?

Best Regards

Comment: maybe it is a security feature to use the password for the first time and on next boot you can use your provider?

Comment: No. I checked logging in the first time using password but the next time again it was only showing the password option. Sign-in options were still not shown for this new user. Is it related to any setting for default credential provider? Or is it related to credential provider filtering? Or some other thing that I will have to do?

Comment: @magicandre1981 I haven't still figured out the issue. I havent received a reply other than yours. Can you help in any way? Regards

Comment: nope, I have no idea. Ask it in the Microsoft forums

Comment: Hi, just an observation I made - when I encountered the identical issue on Win 8.1 with V2 CP added to it   I ** changed the GUID ** for the Sample CP(has to be done in .reg registry files too!), and then rebuilt the code and it seems like  ALL login accounts are now using the Sample V2 Credential Provider DLL, (as I have a log file to log debug messages from this DLL ONLY). But the Sign-In Options choice is STILL only visible for the first(from left) Login Account. But the Sample CP DLL is being invoked, even for DEFAULT password editbox .